# Firebase Invites to Custom Apps

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-invites

I have gone through the firebase invites documentation and implemented the parts I needed on my apps. However I found out that I am limited to sending invites by email/sms. This somehow limits the potential of sending invites to only people who are in your contact list.

For example I cannot send an invite to all my friends on a social platform unless they are in my phone contacts.

Is there a way to go around this?
Is Firebase planning to expand their invites platform?